# printing elements of array in arraylist in java

Tags: java

I do have this code, and I would like to print out all the array's values of Arraylist.
thanks for your help in advanced.

here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) {
        System.out.println("list #" + i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list[i].size(); j++) {
            list[i].get(j);

            System.out.println("elements of array in arraylist "+list[i].get(j));


        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes... no.... 12? What was the question again? It looks like you are printing out some stuff, is it the wrong stuff?

Comment: What is the line list[I].get(j) for?

Comment: I was trying to get the values. but it is not working well

Comment: Trying to guess the format of your data structure is a lot harder than you pasting it with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For printing elements of an array stored in arraylist,you will have to to do the following:

```
for each element of arraylist
 get array from arraylist
   for each array element in array
       print array element.
```

You seemed to be iterating array of List type instead.

Edit your code with further detail on your data structure

Answer (score 4):

See if this can work for you.  I think it's simpler:

```
int numLists = 10;   // Or whatever number you need it to be.
ArrayList [] arrayOfLists = new ArrayList[numLists];
// you realize, of course, that you have to create and add those lists to the array.  
for (ArrayList list : arrayOfLists) {
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

I'd wonder why you don't prefer a List of Lists:

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
// add some lists of Strings
for (List<String> list : listOfLists) {
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Object[] array : list)
  for (Object o : array)
    System.out.println("item: " + o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for me

```
public class Solution
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int T,N,i,j,k=0,Element_to_be_added_to_the_array;

        Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
        T=sn.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer>[] arr=new ArrayList[T];
        for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            arr[k]=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            N=sn.nextInt();
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                Element_to_be_added_to_the_array=sn.nextInt();
                arr[k].add(Element_to_be_added_to_the_array);
            }
            k++;
        }

//Printing elements of all the arrays contained within an arraylist

    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("array["+i+"]");
        for(j=0;j<arr[i].size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i].get(j));
        }   
    }
    }
}
```